# Will accessing an application on local system using IP and accessing it using remote system using same IP , Will output differ, If so why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04, vs-web-application-project

I am running an application developed by me on my local system with 
IP (eg - http://192.168.0.126/career_app/name/controller_name/method_name/).

When I am accessing the same on my system, the output is as desired!!

But when I switch to my laptop connected onto the same network and access the application using the same IP (eg - http://192.168.0.126/career_app/name/controller_name/method_name/) - The same application acts all weird, wrong redirections and wrong flash messages start appearing on the screen.

Comment: What wrong message is displayed ??

Comment: I'd check if some resources within the application aren't configured to use localhost instead.

Comment: check your config.php for the entry `$config['base_url']`, if its using `localhost`, change it to the IP address

Comment: @Bugfixer - No wrong message is being displayed, But the redirection that had to happen to page A is now redirecting to page B. No code has been changed from the time it was working fine and it is still working fine on the system i used for development!

Comment: @Sanchit - All the changes are done well before i encountered this. the $config is **$config['base_url'] =  'http://192.168.0.126/career_portal/hithesh/';**

Comment: So thats where you are wrong I guess, according to your question it should be `http://192.168.0.126/career_app/` and you are using `http://192.168.0.126/career_portal/hithesh/`

Comment: @sanchit - No , lol. Im sorry the application name is career_portal and I am using the same. I just made it simpler for you guys to answer .  Im still not able to  come out with the solution. All these minor errors have been looked into and already corrected!

Comment: When you open the Browser Inspector, do you see any error in the console? If yes, show us the error.

Comment: @sanchit - They are no errors on the console either.!

Comment: @sanchit - I have also been using **.htaccess** as well. I dont know what else i should do to get this project up and running.

Comment: when you calling a method AA from controller A your page is redirected to other controller B method BB. Is this right ?

Comment: @bugfixer - No . it is actually redirecting to the same controller and method again and the fields that we input becomes empty after the button click. But the db is being updated continuously

Comment: using form helper ? with echo form_open('A/AB')

Comment: @Bugfixer - No I Am not using any form helper. I am using Email Helper class though - Codeigniter

Comment: db updated with correct same values which u filled in form.

Comment: @Bugfixer: yes all such errors are already looked into.!